# Как объединить все спаны с анимацией?

Tags: javascript

У меня раздутый код - дохрена спанов, потому что текстовую анимацию делал без библиотеки. Есть ли способ обернуть уже имеющиеся спаны во что-то, но чтобы анимация не потерялась? Просто обернуть, чтобы

1. Был редактируемым блок с этими спанами (подразумеваю редактирование с помощью визуальных редакторов)
2. Уменьшить этот код (все спаны располагаются в текстовом блоке с одним и тем же классом)

Буду благодарен за наводки

Comment: Без примера кода никто помочь не сможет!

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko так здесь вопрос не с кодом помочь. Если это принципиально - скоро добавлю к вопросу

Comment: Просто ваш вопрос звучит следующим образом: У меня проект, в нем много элементов, я хочу сделать редактирование редактором и уменьшить код. Как мне это сделать?